# Change scrollbar height in firefox

Tags: css

I want to change scrollbar height like this image (only for example)[image]

I tried use ::webkit--scrollbar css properties and have got required behavior in chrome but firefox  doesn't suport it.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Read this: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/#comment-92028

Answer (score 0):

You can put your content inside a `div` tag and wrap it by another `div` outside, then set `max-height` for the inner `div i.e:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgb(254 249 195);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 1px 2px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
}

#inner {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ffffff;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #8f54a0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```